# How to remove NA values and the row above and below

Tags: r, na

How can I remove a NA value in R and at the same time, the row above and below the NA value? The NA's are in 2 different columns in a large dataset

So in total removing 3 rows at the time for each NA.

```
Center_x Center_y
200.3    400
NA       200.2
300      100
400.1    450
200      100
100      NA
200      100
```

I want to get

```
Center_x Center_y
400.1    450
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only 1 NA en the complete column1:

```
na_row <- is.na(df$column1)

na_row_number <- which(is.na(na_row))

remove_rows <- c((na_row_number-1):(na_row_number+1))

df <- df[-remove_rows,]
```

I think this should work

Comment: Does this also work for a large dataset with a lot of NA's? The NA's are in 2 different columns

Comment: Yes, It should work but you have to do it once for each column

Comment: I get an error when I try to run the 'remove_rows'. It says argument of length 0.

Comment: When I remove the 'is.na' in the second line of code it works, but it will only remove 1 NA in the entire column